# mysql connector python execute multiple statement

Tags: mysql-connector-python

I would like to execute multiple statements by mysql connector. The code is as below,

```py
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='******',
                               database='dimensionless_ideal')
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = ("Select * From conditions_ld; "
       "Select * From conditions_fw; "
       "Select * From results")
cursor.execute(sql, multi=True)
conn.close()
```

When I run this python script, it is keep running for a very long time unless I kill it. No output and error info. What is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried executing the code directly in MySQL Workbench first?

Comment: If the code is taking a very long time (or is seemingly frozen) I'd suggest opening MySQL Workbench and looking at the Client Connections screen to see what statements are being executed (if any).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

It seems that when you use the Multi=True option, the cursor.execute returns an iterator. There is an example on how to use it.